# How to listen to touch events across all apps in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm working on an application that can record typing speed, touch pressure and etc. related to touch data for my research.

Is there any way to listen to touch events whenever the phone is on for **all being used apps**?

Comment: You can not access another app touch events or press events

Comment: Sandboxing won't allow you to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot listen to touch from other apps except your own

To listent to touch events inside your app you can do the following

1) Subclass UIApplication and override the sendEvents method.

```
override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {

    super.sendEvent(event)
    if let touches = event.allTouches {
        for touch in touches where touch.phase == UITouchPhase.began {
            // Handle specific touches
        }
    }
}
```

2) Remove the @UIApplicationMain from AppDelegate

3) Create a main.swift file with the following contents

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
        .bindMemory(
            to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
    NSStringFromClass(<YOUR_UIApplication_Subclass>.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```